# How to POST extra parametre on twitter typeahead for CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, post, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I'm using CodeIgniter with csrf protection enabled and Bootstrap 3 and twitter typeahead 0.9.3
I need to post my query with csrf key. I lost a day searching this. Tried beforeSend option but it doesn't work here is my code:

```
$('input[name="search"]').typeahead({
        name:"companies",
        remote:{
            url:"{/literal}{site_url('tender/search_suppliers')}/{literal}",
            beforeSend:function(jqXhr,settings){
                settings.type = 'POST';
                settings.data = { csrf_test_name: $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name')}
                settings.hasData=true;
                settings.hasContent=true;
                return true;
            }
        }

    });
```

This code is not posting and did not change type from GET to POST
SORRY for my english

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same problem RE: CSRF Protection in codeigniter and running any kind of ajax based function.

I added this function to my main site.js file that is loaded on all of my pages, and therefore gets included in all of my ajax calls:

```
$.ajaxSetup( data: { csrf_test_name: $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name') } );
```

Comment: You answered very latly I had to solve it with GET request. anyway its usefull info to me Thank You!